# Storage replication/mirror over WAN

Tags: networking, virtualization, storage, disaster-recovery

We are looking at storage replication between two data centers (600km apart) to support an active-passive cluster design for disaster recovery.  The OS layer will be mostly Windows Server 2003/2008 with some OpenSuSE Linux used for performance monitoring on VMWare or possibly XenServer.  The primary application service to replicate is Nvision.  Datacenter 1 will have two storage systems for local active-passive or perhaps active-active replication with Datacenter 2 used as a last resport disaster recovery site.

We have a handle on most aspects, but I am looking for specific recommendations on storage platforms that can handle remote replication cleanly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

HP XP/EVA and NetApp boxes do this kind of thing for us all the time using W2K3/8, Oracle on Linux and VMWare. No idea about open-source equivalents though sorry.

Comment: Also, HP just acquired LeftHand systems, their boxes do a great job at this too.

Comment: @Chris, agreed, I'm just not an iSCSI-kinda-guy, but you're right.

Comment: a free opensource solution, with WAN support would be great

Comment: Can this mirroring-over-WAN technology serve as a substitute for SQL Server database replication? Does it mirror real-time or in periodic batches, e.g. hourly, daily?

Comment: Can it - maybe/possibly, some do it synchronously, some asynchronously, it depends on the products. This question was answered a LONG time ago now but still stands, in fact most storage arrays these days offer this kind of functionality, I buy my storage from Infinidat these days by the way.